# IUpdateSearcher.Search() throws 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) when running as NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: c#, com, windows-update

I am working on a Windows Service which runs under the `NETWORK SERVICE` account. One of the features I'd like to add is the ability to enumerate missing Windows Updates on the local server. The problem I've run into is that the [IUpdateSearcher.Search() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatesearcher-search) throws an "Access Denied" exception. Specifically:

`Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

My code looks like this:

```cs
IUpdateSearcher updateSearcher = new UpdateSearcher();
updateSearcher.Online = true;
ISearchResult results = updateSearcher.Search("(IsInstalled = 0)");
foreach (IUpdate2 update in results.Updates) {
    //Do something
}
```

If I add `NETWORK SERVICE` to the local administrators group, this code works, however, that, of course, is not an acceptable solution. Is it possible for me to get this working without local administrative access?

**Edit:** I updated the code snippet above per the [WUA SDK Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/secured-methods-and-properties-in-the-wua-api) by removing the unneeded `UpdateSession` instance. Unfortunately, the problem remains. According to the SDK guide, as long as the invoker is a member of the local **Users** group, `IUpdateSearcher.Search()` should work. **NETWORK SERVICE** is an implicit member of **Users**:

```
USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name                    SID
============================ ========
nt authority\network service S-1-5-20


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name                                       Type             SID                                           Attributes
================================================ ================ ============================================= ==================================================
Mandatory Label\System Mandatory Level           Label            S-1-16-16384
Everyone                                         Well-known group S-1-1-0                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Certificate Service DCOM Access          Alias            S-1-5-32-574                                  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Users                                    Alias            S-1-5-32-545                                  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE                             Well-known group S-1-5-6                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CONSOLE LOGON                                    Well-known group S-1-2-1                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                 Well-known group S-1-5-11                                      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                   Well-known group S-1-5-15                                      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group


PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                Description                               State
============================= ========================================= ========
SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege Replace a process level token             Disabled
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege      Adjust memory quotas for a process        Disabled
SeSecurityPrivilege           Manage auditing and security log          Disabled
SeAuditPrivilege              Generate security audits                  Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege       Bypass traverse checking                  Enabled
SeImpersonatePrivilege        Impersonate a client after authentication Enabled
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege       Create global objects                     Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege Increase a process working set            Disabled


USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

User claims unknown.
```

Comment: NetworkService has minimum privileges on the local computer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account) and most WUA apis are documented to require at least membership to Users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/secured-methods-and-properties-in-the-wua-api so you'll have to choose another account, not necessarily administrator.

Comment: The `NETWORK SERVICE` user does not have permission to do this.

You either want to run as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` or create a local user just for the service. The second will only work if you don't need to authenticate to the domain (if there is one).

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the guidance. I notice that the SDK article indicates that `IUpdateSearcher.Search()` should work if the invoker is at least in the `Users` group. According to the output of `whoami /all`, `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` is an implicit member of `Users`

Comment: One "deny" is enough to prevent access event if you have many "allow". Isn't E_ACCESSDENIED+ "NetworkService has minimum privileges on the local computer" clear enough?